# No such file or directory problem

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, compiling

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I have a folder on my Desktop that includes some files I want to compile.
I try to run this

```
gcc drr.c -o drr -pthread -lcdsl -L./../synch_implementations -I./../synch_implementations
```

but I get the message *no such file or directory*.

I have tried using `cd` to get to the directory of the folder *ddtr_exercise*, but still get the same message (if go with `cd` to the folder *DRR* it says *no such file or directory* for the synch implementations, and if I `cd` to the synch implementations it says no such file or directory for the *drr.c*)

[image: image 1 for folders]

[image: image 2 for folders]

Comment: Install guest additions on the guest system and set up bidirectional clipboard support. Your images are not helpful. Then post text here.

Comment: @N0rbert how do I do that , I am new on linux

Comment: Try to install guest additions from repository with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11`.

Comment: @N0rbert ok I did both what you said , should I try to run my command now?

Comment: Reboot guest, then click *Devices>Shared clipboard* and set *Bidirectional* here. Then execute your command, copy its output and update your question with paste.

Comment: @N0rbert did that , let me run the command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71008/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-maverick98).